# Simple Search provide Status Dynamically

Tags: status, simple-search

I have a simple search form that I would like to submit a status dynamically, is there any way to do this, right now I am using javascript to submit the form and depending on what status options are toggled i would like to limit the status fields it searches.

If I cannot change the available status's on submission, can I restrict the status on the results page something like this?

```
{exp:search:search_results status="closed|draft"}
```

I can always use the template to not display status's on the results page, but I would prefer not to loop over 10 status's for every result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs don't indicate you can set status from the search form but you can [**set status on the search results page**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#status) with the `status="draft|reviewed|published"` parameter .

---

You might also consider these two addons:

**[Super Search](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/)** OR [**Low Search**](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) which both give you more advanced search capabilities.